# How to create game map using 2D array?

Tags: c++

The map contains water, land, mountain.
This map is represented as a class named CMap that has the properties:

A 2D array, having a height and width of 64, of tiles, each an integer, where a value 0 is water,1 is land, 2 is a mountain, 3 is a town, 4 is a
cave and 5 is a castle.

The number of non-water tiles of a world.

The number of populated tiles, namely towns or castles, of a world

Comment: Please explain your question further. As of now it is very unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without specifying an exact answer (since this sounds like a homework/assignment) ...

It sounds like you need an [enumerated type](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/45-enumerated-types/) for your tile-types.

Perhaps something like:

```
enum CMapTile
{
    WATER    = 0,
    LAND     = 1,
    MOUNTAIN = 3,
    TOWN     = 4,
    CASTLE   = 5
};
```

This means you can use the symbolic (and more readable) string name for the number.  For example, specify `LAND` instead of `1`.  It's not necessary to specify the numbers in the definition, but when these lists get longer, you might find yourself having an issue when the type is say `17`, and adding the numbers (even as a comment) makes it easy to look them up.

Depending on what's expected of the work, it may be simply possible to allocate a 2D block of objects statically.  The static option gives you only a fixed-size map, e.g.:

```
CTileMap tiles[64][64];  // Fixed-size 2D array.  (super-boring)
```

Otherwise the space for the map can be allocated dynamically. The dynamic allocation of a 2D map grabs just enough memory at run-time.  It allows you to reserve the exact amount of space the map needs, and thus is more flexible.  However it is more complex, being a two-step process.  You also need to handle the case when someone tries to make a map bigger than what the machine's memory can handle.

So first allocate an array to hold all your rows.  The allocation is that of the **row-pointers**.  This be because your map array is an array of row-pointers and each row-pointer points to an array of CMapTile - a bit like the `argv` variable to `main()` (except that is an array of char*, not CMapTile*).

```
// allocate an array of row-pointers length <map_height>
CMapTile **tiles = new CMapTile*[map_height];
```

Then for each row-pointer, allocate another array for the width:

```
for ( int i=0; i<map_height; i++ )
    tiles[i] = new CMapTile[map_width];  // allocate row[i], length <map_width>
```

This gives you a map which can be accessed:

```
if ( tiles[y][x] == TOWN )
    populated_lands += 1
```

Make sure you handle memory allocation failures - this will be when `new()` returns NULL.

So a map allocation function may look something like this:
`width`, `height` and `tiles` are class member variables

```
bool allocateMap( int map_width, int map_height )
{
    bool result = true;

    // First, do we already have a map allocated?
    // If so, clean it up first
    if ( tiles != NULL )
        deallocateMap();

    width  = map_width;
    height = map_height;

    // allocate space for the tiles in a 2D array.
    // note that a 1D array would probably be better.
    tiles = new CMapTile*[map_height];  // allocate an array of rows
    if ( tiles != NULL )
    {
        // initialise the list of rows first to better handle allocation failures
        for ( int i=0; i<map_height; i++ )
        {   
            tiles[i] = NULL;
        }
        // allocate some memory for each row
        for ( int i=0; i<map_height; i++ )
        {
            tiles[i] = new CMapTile[map_width];  // allocate row[i]
            if ( tiles[i] == NULL )
            {   
                result = false;
                deallocateMap(); // clean up partially allocated map
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // failed to allocate space for row-holder
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using nested `std::vector`s instead of allocating the memory dynamically.